# ReactJS.NET MVC tutorial doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-5.2, reactjs.net

I'm trying to setup a new project in Visual Studio that is going to be MVC 5 with a single page app written in ReactJS. So I followed [the guide on the ReactJS website](http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html).

I got to the very first part where you run the project, and I got a syntax error because of the JSX (the browser seemed to want to interpret it as vanilla JavaScript which makes perfect sense).  So I added `type="text/jsx"` to the script tag.

In total, my HTML/JSX looks like this:

**HTML output by Razor view**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="/Scripts/Tutorial.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Tutorial.jsx**

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment-box">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I don't understand - what have I done wrong?  I've followed the tutorial to the letter aside from adding `type="text/jsx"` to the script tag.  I'm assuming something needs to be included to handle transforming the JSX into vanilla JS, but the tutorial doesn't seem to mention this.

**I'm not getting any errors at all in the Chrome Developer Tools console.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out - the tutorial is missing two things:

1. The script inclusion should be done thus, with a type declaration:

   `<script type="text/jsx" src="/Scripts/Tutorial.jsx"></script>`
2. The JSX transformer needs to be included:

   `<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>`

So the full HTML output by the Razor view should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="/Scripts/Tutorial.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looks like they need to update their tutorial.

**Update:**

Commenter @DanielLoNigro added this helpful tip:

*Actually if you're using ReactJS.NET, you don't need to use the client-side JSXTransformer. Just ensure that the JSX handler is configured in your Web.config file (there should be a handler for .jsx).*

Comment: Actually if you're using ReactJS.NET, you don't need to use the client-side JSXTransformer. Just ensure that the JSX handler is configured in your Web.config file (there should be a handler for *.jsx).

Comment: @DanielLoNigro that's an invaluable tip, thank you so much! Had no idea about that.

Answer (score 3):

This is how the .jsx handler can be registered in web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
  <remove name="Babel" />
  <add name="Babel" verb="GET" path="*.jsx" type="React.Web.BabelHandlerFactory, React.Web" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

and in this case there is no need to have type="text/jsx" in script tag.

Answer (score 3):

For me, even though my system was 64bit, I had to install `JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x86`instead of `JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x64` and it solved the problem. It will interesting to hear why should I have to install x86 package.

PS: Mind you, that was for ASP.Net MVC though.

Comment: Same here. I am interested why. I hate 32bits apps.

Comment: Same - When using x64 I am getting a 500 error in the console.

Comment: you saved my life. But just very curious why so many people got this issue and the official website doesn't mention anything about that

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to ensure is that you are indeed creating an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and not an ASP.NET Core, as the tutorials are different.

For ASP.NET MVC 4 & 5: https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial_aspnet4.html
For ASP.Net Core: https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html

If you are creating an ASP.NET MVC 5 application then follow the steps below:

**Steps:**

1. Create a new MVC 5 project.
2. In the package manager console, install the following NuGet packages:

> Install-Package react.js
>
> Install-Package React.Web.Mvc4

*You will notice that a folder called 'react' will be created in 'Scripts'*

3. In the Scripts folder create a new '.jsx' file and name it:

> Tutorial.jsx

*This is your where your react code will go.*

4. Copy the following code into your newly created '.jsx' file:

```html
var CommentBox = React.createClass({ 
    render: function() { 
        return (
          <div className="commentBox">
            Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
          </div>
        ); 
     } 
   }); 

ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox />, 
     document.getElementById('content') 
);
```

5. In your `Index` view, which is in the Home folder under views, place the following code:

```html
@{ Layout = null; }
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello React</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/react/react.js ")"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/react/react-dom.js ")"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/Tutorial.jsx ")"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now if you run the application you should get the following in your browser window: 'Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.'