# React is failing to render simple Hello World in MVC project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I got starting ASP.NET MVC project with the following resources added:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

<script src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Section scripts in Index.cshtml:

```
<div id="root"></div>

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/ReactJS/Index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
}
```

And the file itself:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The result is empty page with no errors.
I do not want to use Node.js, I do not want to use even require.js and babel.js, but it seems I have to.
What are the minimal dependencies of reactjs to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure ReactJS core files & Remarkable.js referenced properly as this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/[version]/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/[version]/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/[version]/remarkable.min.js"></script>
```

(more info: [ReactJS MVC](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial_aspnet4.html) / [ReactJS Core MVC](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html))

Then, add JSX file in either `<head>` tag or `Scripts` section:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/ReactJS/Index.jsx"></script>
}
```

Assume in your `<body>` tag has this div container to bind...

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Then, in JSX file the React script should be looks like this:

```js
// Index.jsx
var Root = React.createClass({
               render: function () {
                       return (
                          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                       );
               }
           });

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

As the tutorial page said, BabelJS required if you want to use ES6 features such as arrow functions & concise methods, or use bundling mechanism (`BabelBundle` instead of plain `ScriptBundle`) to load JSX file.

Related issue:

[ReactJS.NET MVC tutorial doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205649/reactjs-net-mvc-tutorial-doesnt-work)

Comment: I did remove babel and require.js from my page. Also it seems I do not need remarkable.js. I changed the js file to jsx and the type of <script> to "text/jsx". One more thing, I did add JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js to the code, and now it is rendering.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use div before h1**

```
var Root = React.createClass({
           render: function () {
                   return (<div>
                      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>  </div>);
           }
       });
```